# exit loop and restart, extract help iMacros and Javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, if-statement, restart, imacros

Hi I'm new on imacros and also javascript, well I did this script to make my macro loop forever (succesfully run macro=1) and when and error happens(-921) run another macro (Which close all tabs go to about:blank and wait 60 seconds) but then the macro stops but I want it to continue the loop as it started I read about end do and exit if but i don't know where to insert it. Can anyone help me? Here is the script
[code]
var ret;

```
do 
    {
    ret = iimPlay("macro.iim");

    if (ret == -921)iimPlay("macro2.iim");
    } while (ret == 1)
```

[/code]
Also I'm trying to do and extract but only numbers, this is what I get OK|92374941 I tried whit the text extractor on imacros 10 but it extracts all the text but I only want 92374941 so as text extractor can't get me what I want I found a code to copy the name and last name but separate because they are placed in the same tag. http://www.fakenamegenerator.com/gen-male-nl-ca.php

```
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO

TAG POS=1 TYPE=H3 ATTR=TXT:*<SP> EXTRACT=TXT

SET VAR1 eval("\"{{!EXTRACT}}\".match(/^\\s*\\S+/)[0]")

SET VAR2 eval("\"{{!EXTRACT}}\".match(/^\\s*\\S+\\s+(.+)\\s*$/)[1]")

PROMPT "VAR1={{VAR1}}, VAR2={{VAR2}}"
```

What can I do to only copy then numbers from  `"Ok|92374941"` 
Hope that someone can help me.

Comment: You can use iimGetLastExtract() to take the values and then let the JS do the rest.

Comment: I solve the extract thing replacing .match for .slice(number). But what I want now is the first thing

Comment: Did u add into imacros code SET !TIMEOUT_MACRO 60 ?

Comment: yes but that is not the problem the website where I am using is kinda buggy and laggy

Comment: Try with SET !ERRORIGNORE YES in the script. If that doesn't work try with try catch method. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch